# Must I derate multiple electrical wires under my bonus room insulated subfloor between floor joists (parallel) if I air seal the space at knee walls

Tags: electrical

I have 15 and 20 amp wires running together between the floor joists unsecured in my attic/bonus room above my insulated garage.  I'm finishing the framed bonus room and will insulate the knee walls and ceiling. The subfloor of the bonus room was installed by the original builder. The wires run underneath that parallel to the joist from knee wall to knee wall and that space (under the subfloor) is insulated with blown-in cellulose. I want to air-seal each end of the bay at the knee wall to make each joist bay airtight, but the electrical wires may pose a problem. I may not be able to make the bays airtight with all the wires as they could require derating due to overheating risk being so close together according to some folk's interpretation of the NEC.  I know I'm ok if I leave them open as the house came this way.  But I don't want cold air circulating under those bays from the unconditioned attic.  I've attached some pics to illustrate.  Can I seal them? Must I use the charts in Cod 310.15 b 2 a?  I can't derate as the wires run all over the house and to the panel. Too expensive.

Comment: Are these wires or cables? How many in how much space?

Comment: I don't see any pictures.